# Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread

Tags: apache-2.2, start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apache2 is not starting my webserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/137769/apache2-is-not-starting-my-webserver)

When I try to restart my webserver apache puts "Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread" in the error log.

I'm not sure what this means, is my server running out of memory...? Or what's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

Double post of:

[Apache2 is not starting my webserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/137769/apache2-is-not-starting-my-webserver/137782#137782)

This post is less active, consider removal?